# AWS EC2: Moving two web apps from 1 instance to 4 instances (2 each)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

Our current setup:

two independent web applications, running on one EC2 m3.medium instance (two apps share one ec2 instance)

we use VirtualHosts (1 IP and 2 domains, which are being routed using VirtualHost in httpd.conf)

Our desired setup:

our two apps running on two m1.small instance each (4x m1.small in total)

It was recommended to us by another stackoverflow user, as it will

a) increase reliability (if one instance crashes, the service will not be interrupted)

b) opens possibility to add more instances depending on the load of each application (if app A is growing much faster than B, we can scale A without affecting B)

---

Now we are working on a plan on how to do this. My idea was to make the following changes (in this order):

1) set up each app twice on one m1.small, consuming 4 instances in total

```
AppA1, AppA2, AppB1, AppB2
```

2) set up two load balancers with two new elastic IPs for each duo of m1.small

```
loadbalancerA->AppA1, AppA2 
loadbalancerB->AppB1, AppB2
```

3) change the respective app-domain's A-record to the new ip of the newly created load balancer

---

Is this the way to go, or did we miss something?

Also, is our strategy in general (separating the two apps, plus adding redundancy by adding multiple instances) a good way to follow?

I am as always forever grateful for your valuable input, and will be looking forward to your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use similar approach in my company. So yes it's globally correct. You can even add autoscaling on top of that.
For the point 2: You will have to use CNAME and not A record if you want to use Load Balancer. They do not have IPs but a dns name.

But I think it could be interesting for you to have a look at AWS Beanstalk.

A) increase reliability => automatically replace unhealthy instance with new one (autoscaling group)

B) autoscaling group created automatically with beanstalk, you set up cpu % or network output etc. and it will autoscale by itself. No need for human intervention. You set up a minium and maximum of server for your application.

C/ Easy to set up. I'm not an sysadmin and was able to do it.

We have 7 websites running on beanstalk, on 6 m3.medium during normal hours and up to 30 m3.medium during peak hours and everything is automated. Sometime, an instance crash during deployment (usually because of some timeout), the Load balancer find it unhealthy then terminate it automatically and it is replaced by a new one within a few minutes.

Else, if you are already using puppet, get a look at opswork.

Comment: Thanks for your input, very interesting. Do you have those 7 websites separated (1 instance each during normal load, up to 5 instances each during peak)? Or are all websites deployed to all instances? In our case the apps are very different from each other (one is our webservices from our mobile app, mostly communicating with our RDS instance, and other is full html/js web application). Due to these different needs, I believe it makes sense to divide them into two "groups" of instances that can be scaled as needed. Also, beansalk and opswork look both very interesting, will look into those.

Comment: Im glad I could help.  We have separate application (instance/configuration) in beanstalk for each of these websites and I would advise to do the same. About Rds, we share the same instance across several websites as it is not our bottleneck so you can definitely do the same.